# Find the maximum in the table and then display the SQL group and the count of maximum in each and every SQL group respectively

Tags: mysql, sql

```
ID  POSITION    EXPERIENCE  SALARY
1   top               90    1500
2   bottom           100    1500
3   top               90    750
4   left              90    1000
5   right            100    1300
6   top               90    1500
7   left              80    2000
8   top               80    1000
9   bottom           100    2000
10  left             100    2000
```

So, this is my table SERVICE where(as we can see) the maximum experience is 100.
I need to write a query to find the number of occurences of 100 in experience in each and every group  made through position(left, right, top, bottom).

so I wrote:-

```
select position,count(*)
from service
group by position
having experience=(select max(experience) from service);
```

Expected Output:-

```
POSITION  COUNT(*)
bottom         2 
left           1
right          1
top            0
```

But,
It gives me an error saying :- "not a GROUP BY expression"

My logic is that, first I am dividing it into groups and then using having clause I am counting those tuples in each group where the experience equals max. experience.

Comment: `having` is only for comparing an aggregate - sum, max, etc. You want to use `where experience = ...`

Comment: yeah, if is use where experience=(select max exp..) from service) , then use group by and count the number of tuples in each group, it won't show me "top 0" in the answer because there is no group formed with top as no tuple having position='top' has experience=maximum experience........

Comment: So , u said that having can be used only for comparing aggregates, I get it....But, my follow up question would be, Is there no way of counting the tuples after grouping that satisfy a condition???

Comment: Thanks, I am new to stackoverflow... I went through both the answers and both were doing the work, but the first one did it in a very simple way and it also taught me how to count those tuples in an SQL group which satisfy a  particular condition..(in this question which was to get those tuples whose experience equals the max experience in an SQL group.... Thanks to everybody answered... But it would be amazing if anybody answered it in Oracle .. coz these queries give error in Oracle, but works fine for MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sum`:

```
select position, sum(experience = 100) from tbl group by position
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8ngJIe84).

Comment: It works as well for when maximum value is not explicitly specified....                          
 `select position, sum(experience=(select max(experience) from tbl)) from tbl group by position; `   https://dbfiddle.uk/HGZ6m3tM   .... But  it only works in MySQL , not oracle .

Answer (score 1):

One way is using left join with a subquery wich will return only the maximum value . The case is needed to return the groups which have any max value.

```
SELECT s.position,
       sum(case when max_experience is null then 0 else 1 end ) as max_count
FROM service s
LEFT JOIN  ( select max(experience) as max_experience
             from service 
            ) as s1 ON  s.experience = s1.max_experience
group by s.position
order by max_count desc ;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/-8pHZ8wm

To make more easy to understand run below query and you will the that max_experience is null in every row of service table except for the value 100. In simple words you need to count only the rows with value 100 and 0 for the groups which hasn't the the max experience value.

```
SELECT s.*,s1.*
FROM service s
LEFT JOIN  (select max(experience) as max_experience
             from service 
            ) as s1 ON  s.experience = s1.max_experience ;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/al8YYLk9

*Edit*. The answer works in Oracle as well, but the keyword `as` after the subquery needs to be removed

```
SELECT s.position,
       sum(case when max_experience is null then 0 else 1 end ) as max_count
FROM service s
LEFT JOIN  ( select max(experience) as max_experience
             from service 
            )  s1 ON  s.experience = s1.max_experience
group by s.position
order by max_count desc ;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/hhGB_xXx